# What do these circles have in common - and what not?

Tags: visual, enigmatic-puzzle

> The image below shows 7 x 7 grey circles which all *but one* share a common attribute. Can you see this shared property, or rather: Can you see which circles does *not* belong to the group and give a reason?

A complete answer must of course contain an explanation. To identify the circles, simply number them, i.e `3rd column, 5th row` or such. I did not want to complicate the image with labels.

[image: The puzzle is all in here]

Note, you do not need to look at the digital content or super high resolution, nor do you need any digital processing of the image. It also contains only 8 distinct colours.

Comment: That's one heck of a lot of a red herrings

Comment: If you miss it then its all over. No solve, Too late.

Comment: This is horribly cruel and I love it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of the circles

> shrinks, the rest do not.  This is an animated GIF.  The circle in the second row (from the top), sixth column (from the left) shrinks every 60 seconds:
>
> [image]

Comment: Quick ;c) I was toying with an yet un-explored property and wanted a *time* related puzzle. Did you *see* it, or explore digitally?

Comment: I saw it and thought my eyes might have been playing tricks on me.  Then I verified it [here](http://ezgif.com/split).

Comment: Nice and as I hoped/expected. I didn't want to put a longer delay in, as this "puzzle" shouldn't become an annoyance. I wanted to test the idea and if it would work. Didn't expect it to be solved *that* fast though. (2min before I could accept an answer!!)

Answer (score 3):

Excellent find by [pacoverflow](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/17206/9000) but here's a more obvious rule:

> All but one of the circles sits on no more than 2 fields of color. The odd circle out, therefore, is 5th row from the top, 3rd column from the left. It sits on 6 fields of color.

With all of the very intentional red herrings, there are probably more rules like that but what pacoverflow found is definitely what was intended.

Comment: With the puzzle specifically mentioning that circle, I think it's pretty clear that it wasn't the intended solution.

Comment: @IanMacDonald I missed that reference because it's given as the location. Oh, man, what a twist for a puzzle! Put the actual answer as a throwaway example in the text. I'm going to remember that idea.

Comment: +1 for the alternative solution. Might have accepted it, if it would have been the first. BTW, my original plan was to have some eye-blinking owls ;c)  But I thought people had enough owls for a while...

Comment: @BmyGuest Never enough owls. Mods are asleep. Post more owls.